# React Firebase data is undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a fintech website, and I have a users collection and a transactions collection. One user can send money to another user by using their phone number.

The user schema contains these

```
uid - string
phone - string
.....//other data
```

I need to achieve the following functionality

1. Enter phone number of target receiver
2. Get details of user with the entered phone number
3. Add this data to another collection called transactions

I tried doing that, but I'm getting a bug that in the 3rd step, the data from the 2nd step is undefined. Here's my code

```js
const SendMoney = () => {

    const [receiverDetails, setRecieverDetails] = useState({})
    const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = useState([])
    const [receiverphone, setReceiverphone] = useState('')

    const usersCollectionRef = collection(db, "users")
    const getAllUsers = async () => {
        const data = await getDocs(usersCollectionRef)
        setAllUsers(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllUsers()
    }, [])

    const getRecieverDetails = (phone) => {
        const receiver = allUsers.filter(u => u.phone === phone)[0]
        setRecieverDetails(receiver)
    }

    const makeTransaction = async () => {
        getRecieverDetails(receiverphone)
        console.log(receiverDetails)  --------> prints {}

        
        const transactionsCollectionRef = collection(db, "transactions")
        await addDoc(transactionsCollectionRef,
            {
                toUser: receiverDetails.uid,
                //other data
            }
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Send money</h2>
            <input placeholder='phone number' onChange={e => setReceiverphone(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="number" onChange={e => setAmount(e.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={makeTransaction}>send money</button>
        </div>

    )
}

export default SendMoney
```

My guess is that the addDoc function is called before the receiverDetails gets populated with data. I am not sure how to fix this bug

Answer (score 0):

Calls to `setState` or the setter of a `useState` hook are asynchronous.

Don't use state to pass data between your own pieces of code, but instead use normal variables, and promises or `async`/`await` to synchronize.

```
const SendMoney = () => {
    const [receiverDetails, setRecieverDetails] = useState({})
    const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = useState([])
    const [receiverphone, setReceiverphone] = useState('')
    let users; //  new variable

    const usersCollectionRef = collection(db, "users")
    const getAllUsers = async () => {
        const data = await getDocs(usersCollectionRef)
        users = data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })); //  This is synchronouse
        setAllUsers(users); //  This is asynchronous
    }

    useEffect(() => {
    }, [])

    const getRecieverDetails = (phone) => {
        await getAllUsers()
        const receiver = users.filter(u => u.phone === phone)[0]
        setRecieverDetails(receiver)
    }
```